# How to set inbox refresh rate in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do I set the inbox refresh rate in Outlook?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's very simple to set refresh rate in Outlook.

Just go to `File >> Options >> Advanced >> Send and receive option is available...`

Set the time.

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>

Update it here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2007 settings are under

```
Tools >> Send/Receive >> Send/Receive Settings >> Define Send/Receive Groups.....
```

Or use shortcut given by Jay

`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `s`